# Rigorous proof that a line maps to a circle on the sphere?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I'm solving some exercises for practice and I'm not so sure about my attempt at an answer for  this one:

Suppose $T \subset \mathbb C$. Show that the corresponding set $S \subset \Sigma$ is

a. a circle if $T$ is a circle.

b. a circle minus $(0,0,1)$ if $T$ is a line.

Here $\Sigma$ is the sphere $\{(x,y,z) \mid x^2 + y^2 + (z-{1\over 2})^2 = {1\over 4}\}$ minus $(0,0,1)$.

I solved a) but b) seems to be somewhat less easy. Here is my attempt at an answer. I feel that it's not really a rigorous proof. Or maybe it is? I can't tell anymore.

> Please could someone check this and tell me what a correct fully
>   rigorous proof-answer would be for b)?

Let $T$ be a line in the plane. Then points in $T$ are of the form $AX + BY = C$. This equation defines a plane in $\mathbb R^3$. The intersection of this plane with $\Sigma$ corresponds to the points on $\Sigma$ that correspond to $T$. Points in this intersection are of the form:

$$ A {x \over x^2 + y^2 + 1} + B {y \over x^2 + y^2 + 1} = C$$

i.e.

$$ Ax + By = C (x^2 + y^2 + 1) = Cx^2 + Cy^2 + C$$

But the equation

$$ Cx^2 - Ax + Cy^2 - By = C$$

defines a circle in $\Sigma$.

Comment: Shouldn't a plane in $\Bbb{R}^3$ depend on $Z$ as well?

Comment: @Semiclassical No. Is this why you down voted?

Comment: No, I wasn't the downvote. Though I do think your statements seem a bit off; I'll see if I can put together an answer to that end.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a geometric version of your argument, stated in terms that seem sound to me. We have a line $Ax+By=C$ in the plane (Cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$). The set of lines passing through the north pole $(0,0,1)$ that intersects the line $Ax+By=C$ is itself a plane. (Namely, the plane $Ax+By=C(1-z)$: it includes $(0,0,1)$, and for $z=0$ one recovers the line in the plane.)

This plane certainly intersects the sphere---it includes the north pole, after all---and such an intersection generates a spherical circle that passes through the north pole. Hence this spherical circle is the stereographic projection of the line.